# Why doesn't this program output one integer at the end of the loop?

Tags: java

So a jist of what the program needs to do is to count how many integers are greater than the average of the sum of all elements in an array. It does this as the last number it counts is the total number of integers greater than average. However, it also shows the number of times it has looped. For example, if the number of integers is supposed to be 3, it will show, 1,2,3. That's fine but the 1,2, the part is not necessary, just the 3. This is the only way I have found possible but is there a better way?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sparky

{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
  int sum =0;
  int n;
  do
  {
     System.out.print("Enter integer n, greater than 0: ");
     n = kbd.nextInt();
  }while(n < 1);      
  System.out.println();

  int[] arr = new int[n];
  System.out.println("Array on one line: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
     arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 500) + 1;
     System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
  }
  int max = arr[0];     
  for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
     if(arr[i] > max)
     {
        max = arr[i];
     }
  }
  System.out.println();

  {
  double x = 0;
  double y;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
     x = arr[i] + x;
  }
  y = x / arr.length;
  System.out.println("Average: " + y);

  System.out.println("Number of integers greater than average: ");
  int count = 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
  {
     if(arr[i] > y)
     {         
        System.out.print(count + ",");
        count ++;              
        }         
      }          
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Well you are printing at the same place that you are incrementing.  It seems simple to just not print there.  Simply have count++; without the print statement.  Then it will stop printing there.  Now you can go down a few braces to the very end of the function, outside of all the loops and put a print statement that only gets reached at the end of the function.  This is trivial.

Comment: Hey Joe! If you found a solution that solved your problem, you should accept that answer to help others who come along after you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last section of your code from this :

```
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
  {
     if(arr[i] > y)
     {         
        System.out.print(count + ",");
        count ++;              
     }         
  }
```

To this :

```
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
  {
     if(arr[i] > y)
     {
         count ++;
     }
  }
  System.out.print(count);
```

It should print the number of integers greater than average.

Answer (score 1):

Xerox's answer was good, but I noticed a bug in your code. If you start count at 1, your count will be off. Also, I thought I'd show you how to use a foreach loop. So I made some updates to your code, ran it, and added comments for you. Remember, short variable names were used in the 80s because they took up disk space and slowed down processing time when they were larger. That's no longer an issue, and if your variable names are cryptic, your code is difficult to read, even when it's simple. You'll notice that your code is much easier to read with descriptive variable names and a foreach loop. I left the rest of the file for you to do if you are interested.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sparky {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter integer n, greater than 0: ");
            n = kbd.nextInt();
        } while (n < 1);
        System.out.println();

        int[] arr = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Array on one line: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 500) + 1;
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        int max = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        {
            double x = 0;
            double average; //Better to have readable variables. "y" means nothing, "average" is clear, especially in the next section.
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                x = arr[i] + x;
            }
            average = x / arr.length;
            System.out.println("Average: " + average);

            int numberGreaterThanAverage = 0; //This needs to start at 0 or your count will be off. Also, name the variable what it does. Short variable names help no one.
            for (int number: arr) { //This is called a foreach loop. It does the same thing as your loop, but is much each to read, also I renamed "i", short for "iterator" to "number" which is what it actually is, a number in the array.
                if (number > average) {
                    numberGreaterThanAverage++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Number of integers greater than average: " + numberGreaterThanAverage); //This needed to be moved out of the loop, and it also could be concatenated with the rest of the text to put it all on one line.
        }
        kbd.close(); //You need to close this or you can get a memory leak
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always consider printing statements **after** you are done with modifying the values, best is to print outside the loop.

In this case, Count is being printed before it is incremented, on the last iteration of the loop, it increments and quits the loop.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
  {
     if(arr[i] > y)
     {         
        // System.out.print(count + ","); count is being printed before it is incremented
        count ++;              
     }         
  }
  System.out.print(count + ","); //Should be printed **after** the loop ends.
```